# NSWindowDelegate functions cannot work

Tags: macos, swift, delegates, nswindow

I'm writing an application using NSWindowDelegate. However, when I resize the window, it doesn't call function:

> func windowDidResize(notification: NSNotification)

This is my class

> class ViewController: NSViewController, **NSWindowDelegate** {}

and the storyboard:

[This is my storyboard](http://i748.photobucket.com/albums/xx128/letatanu/Screen%20Shot%202015-09-05%20at%203.52.41%20AM.png)

I linked delegate to my window. 
But it doesn't work. Can you help me fix the error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared your window delegate with:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {}
```

When your screenshot shows the window controller, not the view controller, as being designated as the delegate.

Set your window controller to be the delegate recipient.  E.G.:

```
class MyWindowController : NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate {}
```

Comment: anyway to set delegate = viewController? What if I use NSViewController, how can i tell it that window was resized?

Comment: hi @flinth - you can set the window controller to be the delegate of the window (either programatically or via a connection in the storyboard or XIB file) and any time the window has been resized, the appropriate delegate method will be called.